# problema ao remover tab de um tabcontrol c#

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp

Estou tentando remover uma tabcontrol, essa tabcontrol está com o cef aberto(navegador com motor do google chrome) nele tenho um button chamado sair.
Ele é criado assim:

```
TabPage nova = new TabPage();
nova.Text = "aba1"; //aba 2 assim por diante
tabControl1.Controls.Add(nova);
chromeBrowser.Add(new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://sitedoprojeto.com/index.html"));
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tabControl1.Controls.Count-1;
chromeBrowser[chromeBrowser.Count - 1].Parent = tabControl1.SelectedTab;
chromeBrowser[chromeBrowser.Count - 1].RegisterJsObject("cefCustomObject", new CefCustomObject(chromeBrowser[chromeBrowser.Count - 1], this, nova));
```

Já tentei várias maneiras, passando o ultimo parametro acima "nova", tambem tentei passar pra ele chromeBrowser[chromeBrowser.Count - 1].Parent, e também ja tentei remover direto a aba selecionada, todas as tentativas resultaram no erro abaixo:
Uma explicacao em codigo:

no javascript chamo o metodo sair cefCustomObject.sair();

No script cefCustomObject chamo assim:

```
public void sair()
{
     _instanceMainForm.sair(_instanceTabPage);
}
```

E no form eu recebo assim:

```
public void sair(TabPage _instanceTabPage)
    {
        //aqui removo os dados do sistema e entao da erro nesse comando
        tabControl1.Controls.Remove(_instanceTabPage);
    }
```

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operação entre threads inválida: controle '' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.'

Alguem sabe como resolvo isso?

Comment: consegui resolver

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi assim

```
if (tabControl1.InvokeRequired)
            tabControl1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                tabControl1.Controls.Remove(_instanceTabPage);
            });
```